# workflow from java code suspended

Tags: java, hadoop, workflow, oozie

i am running a workflow which has java code which in turn launches another oozie workflow. the main workflow is working fine but the workflow launched from the java code is always in suspended status. i am unable to resume it because the user for that is mapred and not me. any idea what might be the problem?

here's my main workflow

```
<java>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <main-class>com.last.play.LaunchJob</main-class>
        <arg>currentUser=${currentUser}</arg>
     </java>
```

and here's the java code:

```
    Map<String, String> commandArgs = getActionArgs(args);

    Path appPropertyPath = new Path("/user/cmahajan/app.properties");
    Path jobPropertyPath = new Path("/user/cmahajan/job.properties");
    OozieClient wc = new OozieClient("http://host07.com:11000/oozie");

    String userName = commandArgs.get("currentUser");
    System.out.println("User Name recieved ::" + userName);
    Configuration trial = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(trial);

    Properties conf = wc.createConfiguration();
    Properties jobProperties = new Properties();
    Properties appProperties = new Properties();
    appProperties.load(fs.open(appPropertyPath));
    String version = appProperties.getProperty("version");
    jobProperties.load(fs.open(jobPropertyPath));

    for (Object key : jobProperties.keySet()) {
        String propValue = jobProperties.getProperty((String) key);
        propValue = propValue.replaceAll("\\$\\{user.name\\}", userName);
        conf.setProperty((String) key, propValue);
        System.out.println("Key ::" + key);
        System.out.println("Value ::" + propValue);
        System.out.println(" ===================");
    }
    String appsRoot = "${wfsBasePath}/" + version + "/apps";
    conf.setProperty("appsRoot", appsRoot);
    try {
        String jobId = wc.run(conf);

        System.out.println("Workflow job submitted");

        while (wc.getJobInfo(jobId).getStatus() == WorkflowJob.Status.RUNNING) {
            System.out.println("Workflow job running ...");
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        }
        System.out.println("Workflow job completed ...");
        System.out.println(wc.getJobInfo(jobId));
    } catch (OozieClientException oozieClientException) {
        oozieClientException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UserGroupInformation to set the user.

```
UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser(username);
ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<MyMapReduceWrapperClass>() {
public Object run() throws Exception {
    MyMapReduceWrapperClass mr = new MyMapReduceWrapperClass();
    ToolRunner.run(mr, null);
    return mr;
}
});
```